# VBA Trigger Worksheet Change with Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to populate spreadsheet column G with an image file based on the value of column B on the same row of the sheet.  If I manually enter the value into column B everything works great, however I have a long list and was hoping to copy/paste multiple values into column B.  When I paste it seems like the worksheet change is not triggered and column H is not populated with images.  The code I am using is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim shp As Shape
If Intersect(Target, [B:B]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row Mod 20 = 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo son

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoPicture And shp.TopLeftCell.Address = Target.Offset(0, 4).Address Then shp.Delete
Next

If Target.Value <> "" And Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target.Value & ".jpg") = "" Then
        'picture not there!
        MsgBox Target.Value & " Doesn't exist!"
End If

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target.Value & ".jpg").Select
Selection.Top = Target.Offset(0, 5).Top
Selection.Left = Target.Offset(0, 5).Left

With Selection.ShapeRange
.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
.Height = Target.Offset(0, 5).Height
.Width = Target.Offset(0, 5).Width
End With
Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
son:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you paste multiple value the `Target` parameter becomes array of range you paste.
And it is also a array of 1 member if you paste only 1 row.

So, use `For..Next` loop to complete all row you were paste. And change all `Target` to `Target(i)` and change some code as below.

```
For i = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
    If Target(i).Value <> "" And Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target(i).Value & ".jpg") = "" Then
        'picture not there!
        MsgBox Target(i).Value & " Doesn't exist!"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target(i).Value & ".jpg").Select
        Selection.Top = Target(i).Offset(0, 5).Top
        Selection.Left = Target(i).Offset(0, 5).Left

        With Selection.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = Target(i).Offset(0, 5).Height
        .Width = Target(i).Offset(0, 5).Width
        End With
    End If
Next
```